# Android-Development: API to find Rss-Feeds

Tags: android, api, search, rss, feed

I want to write an app where I can search for feeds.
F.e. I write "kicker" und then the app gives me proposals to find the rss I've searched for.

Is there an API or commercial/free website service ?
I  could not find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use Google's feed find API - https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using google feed search API in  my android app and parsing json responses. It does a decent job but not always accurate. Sometimes it gives the home page url of the websites where all the feed links are present.